# Which gatsby-source plugin to use with a Rails api using graphql gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, graphql, gatsby

I'm building a Rails API using the `gem 'graphql'` and want to access this GraphQL API using a `Gatsby.js` front-end.  I've attempted to use [gatsby-source-apiserver](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-apiserver/?=gatsby-source) plugin and [gatsby-source-graphql](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-graphql/), but neither of them seem to work.  (The API works fine when I do queries using the `GraphiQL` app on my local machine.)

Is there a better `Gatsby.js` source plugin what will work well with a Rails API using the `gem 'graphql'`, which provides a single endpoint, `http://localhost:3000/graphql`?  And if so, how should I configure that plugin in `gatsby-config.js`, etc?  (BTW, I'm using a Postgres database which I intend to deploy to Heroku -- I'd thought about pursuing [hasura](https://hasura.io/), but I'm not sure if that's the best option.)

In the Rails API in `routes.rb`, I've set up `post "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute"` to route to `GraphqlController`.  Here is the `execute` method in the Controller...

```
def execute
  variables = ensure_hash(params[:variables])
  query = params[:query]
  operation_name = params[:operationName]
  context = {
    # Query context goes here, for example:
    # current_user: current_user,
  }
  result = GraphqlRailsSchema.execute(query, variables: variables, context: context, operation_name: operation_name)
  render json: result
  rescue => e
  raise e unless Rails.env.development?
  handle_error_in_development e
end
```

When I attempt to render the `json: result`, `result` is: `#<GraphQL::Query::Result @query=... @to_h={"errors"=>[{"message"=>"No query string was present"}]}>` for either of the front-end set-ups I cite below....

In my Gatsby.js front-end, when I use [gatsby-source-apiserver](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-apiserver/?=gatsby-source), in `gatsby-config.js`, I have...

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-apiserver',
  options: {
    typePrefix: 'internal__',
    url: `http://localhost:3000/graphql`,
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {

    },
    name: `posts`,
    entityLevel: `data.posts`,
    payloadKey: `body`,
  }
},
```

...and I get his error in my console when I run `gatsby develop`...

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

And, when I use [gatsby-source-graphql](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-graphql/), I have this in `gatsby-config.js`...

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
  options: {
    // This type will contain remote schema Query type
    typeName: "Authors",
    // This is field under which it's accessible
    fieldName: "authors",
    // Url to query from
    url: "http://localhost:3000/graphql",
  },
},
```

...and I get his error in my console when I run `gatsby develop`...

`Error: Cannot find module 'gatsby/graphql'`

As you can see, I'm confused about how to connect the `schemas` between the front-end and the back-end here.  Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have find any solution?

Comment: Looking for a solution as well